# Kotlin, receiving data from php api too late. Need to press my button twice before data is received by the viewmodel

Tags: php, android, json, api, kotlin

I need to press the "loginbutton" twice, before I am receiving any data. The first time I press the button, I am receiving data: "null". The second time, I am receiving the necessary data for my login. The question is: "How can I receive my data by the first clickevent?"

XML:

```
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/login_login"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

LoginActivity:

```
private lateinit var listIntent: Intent


class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLoginBinding
    private val viewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModels()
    private val EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
        "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
                "\\@" +
                "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
                "(" +
                "\\." +
                "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
                ")+"
    )


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        try {
            this.supportActionBar!!.hide()
        } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
        }
        binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        **binding.loginButton.setOnClickListener() { launchMain() }**
        binding.loginTextNewHereRegister.setOnClickListener() { launchRegister() }
        binding.loginTextForgotPassword.setOnClickListener() { launchPasswordForgot() }
    }


    private fun launchMain() {
        if (binding.loginEmailEditText.text?.isEmpty() == true) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, please put in a email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else if (binding.loginPasswordEditText.text?.isEmpty() == true) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, please put in a password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else if (!isValidString(binding.loginEmailEditText.text.toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Sorry, your email does not meet the requirements.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        } else {
            viewModel.login(
                binding.loginEmailEditText.text.toString(),
                sha256(binding.loginPasswordEditText.text.toString())
            )
            if (viewModel.doorgaan.value == true) {
                listIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(listIntent)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, viewModel.id.value.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               // Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, login credentials are wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                binding.loginPasswordEditText.text?.clear()
            }
        }
    }


    private fun isValidString(str: String): Boolean {
        return EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(str).matches()
    }

    private fun launchRegister() {
        listIntent = Intent(this, RegisterActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(listIntent)
    }

    private fun launchPasswordForgot() {
        listIntent = Intent(this, ForgotPasswordActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(listIntent)
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel.kt

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _status = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val _id = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    private val _doorgaan = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    // The external immutable LiveData for the request status
    val status: MutableLiveData<String> = _status
    val id: MutableLiveData<Int> = _id
    val doorgaan: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = _doorgaan


    /* init {
         setStatus()
     }*/

     fun login(email: String, password: String) {
        _login(email, password)
     }

     private fun _login(email: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            //val loginResult = gson.fromJson(MyApi.retroFitService.login(email,password),DataAccount::class.java)
            //_status.value = loginResult

            val loginResult = MyApi.retroFitService.login(email, password)
            _status.value = loginResult
            if (_status.value == null){
                _status.value = loginResult
            }
            val jsonObject = JSONTokener(MyApi.retroFitService.login(email, password)).nextValue() as JSONObject
            if (jsonObject.length() > 0) {
                val stringArray = jsonObject.getString("data")
                val jsonArray = JSONArray(stringArray)
                for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                    _id.value = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("accountid")
                }
                _doorgaan.value = _id.value != null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyApiService.kt

```
private const val baseUrl = "https://private :)/php/"

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .build()

interface MyApiService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("LOGIN_KOTLIN.php")
    suspend fun login(
        @Field("email") email: String,
        @Field("password") password: String
    ): String

}

object MyApi {
    val retroFitService: MyApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(MyApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

PHPAPI:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select * FROM Account where email like ? and password like ?"); 


if (!$stmt){
    //oeps, probleem met prepared statement!
    $response['code'] = 7;
    $response['status'] = 200; // 'ok' status, anders een bad request ...
    $response['data'] = $conn->error;
    deliver_response($response);
}
// bind parameters
// s staat voor string
// i staat voor integer
// d staat voor double
// b staat voor blob
// "ss" staat dus voor String, String
if(!$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])){
    // binden van de parameters is mislukt
    $response['code'] = 7;
    $response['status'] = 200; // 'ok' status, anders een bad request ...
    $response['data'] = $conn->error;
    deliver_response($response);
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    // het uitvoeren van het statement zelf mislukte
    $response['code'] = 7;
    $response['status'] = $api_response_code[$response['code']]['HTTP Response'];
    $response['data'] = $conn->error;
    deliver_response($response);
}

$result = $stmt->get_result();

if (!$result) {
    // er kon geen resultset worden opgehaald
    $response['code'] = 7;
    $response['status'] = $api_response_code[$response['code']]['HTTP Response'];
    $response['data'] = $conn->error;
    deliver_response($response);
}

// Vorm de resultset om naar een structuur die we makkelijk kunnen 
// doorgeven en stop deze in $response['data']

$response['data'] = getJsonObjFromResult($result); // -> fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)

// maak geheugen vrij op de server door de resultset te verwijderen
$result->free();
// sluit de connectie met de databank
$conn->close();
// Return Response to browser
deliver_response($response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login method is asnychronous, the method will return immediately even if the coroutine is still running (giving null data since it hasn't had time to complete).

**Method 1 - Callback**

One way of handling this would be to pass in a callback like this

```kotlin
fun login(email: String, password: String, onComplete: ()->Unit) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        //do slow/network/suspending stuff
        onComplete()
    }
}
```

then call it like this

```kotlin
viewModel.login(
    binding.loginEmailEditText.text.toString(),
    sha256(binding.loginPasswordEditText.text.toString())
) {
    // the code in here is your "onComplete" callback, and won't run
    // until the login task is done
    if (viewModel.doorgaan.value == true) {
        listIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(listIntent)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, viewModel.id.value.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        binding.loginPasswordEditText.text?.clear()
    }
}
```

**Method 2 - Observe the LiveData (better)**

Alternately, you could have your activity observe the `doorgaan` LiveData and respond when it changes, which would also cause the program to wait appropriately until it had data there (just make sure you always set a value to the data inside `_login`, the current code does not set a value in some cases).

```kotlin
// add this inside onCreate, and remove these calls from launchMain
viewModel.doorgaan.observe(this) { value ->
    if (value == true) {
        listIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(listIntent)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, viewModel.id.value.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        binding.loginPasswordEditText.text?.clear()
    }
}
```

To make sure something always gets posted, you could do something like this inside `_login`

```kotlin
var auth = false
if (jsonObject.length() > 0) {
    val stringArray = jsonObject.getString("data")
    val jsonArray = JSONArray(stringArray)
    for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
        _id.value = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("accountid")
    }
    auth = _id.value != null
}
_doorgaan.postValue(auth)
```